# How to hide and show a layout on scrolling down a scroll view in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I have a particular layout which consist a scroll view and an image which is at bottom of the activity. My question is that when I start scrolling up that image will not visible and when the scroll reach to top it is visible again.

I attached my image link so that you get the idea what I want.

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PoTGvwtGL3gN8uMtF86TjG1FtrWTDCzP]

Comment: you are recyclerview?

Comment: Do you want to hide the image on scroll down? is the image is in the scrollview or in the parent layout?

Comment: No it does not have a recycler view. And the image is also not in scroll view its is in parent layout at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with android support widget [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html).
Follow this [post](http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-hide-floating-action-button-on-when-scrolling-in-recycler-view/) to hide/show the image based on scrolling.

You can learn more about coordinator layout [here](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Answer (score 0):

```
    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if (scrollView != null) {
            if (scrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom() <= (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) {
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is something that you should try out

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getTop());
```

and when it gets to top show the visibility of the image view as visible and in else part make it gone...

Comment: how make condition in this can you please tell me